# Unable to install pyodbc

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, pyodbc

I am using python 3.3.0 .. Within this package C:\Python34\Scripts is my pip and I have added this path to my system and user environment variable PATH the link to this pip folder,I have installed Visual C++ 2010 but i don't know what needs to be done once it is installed if or not i need to configure something, yet when I do :

```
C:\Python33\Scripts>pip install https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
```

It gives me the following error:

**This is what stackoverflow editor has changed it to :**

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
'"C:\Python33\python.exe "  "C:\Python33\Scripts\pip.exe" install
https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyo dbc-3.0.7.zip'

C:\Python33\Scripts>pip 
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
'"C:\Python33\python.exe " "C:\Python33\Scripts\pip.exe" '
```

**And this is the actual error that i see at console:**

> ValueError: ['path']
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> Command "C:\Python33\python.EXE -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c
> ```
>
> \users\elyon\appdata\local\temp\pip-inh3nq-build\setup.py';exec(compi
>   e(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), __fil
>   __, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\elyon\appdata\local\temp\pip-x45j1j-
>   ecord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
>   --compile" failed ith error code 1 in c:\users\elyon\appdata\local\temp\pip-inh3nq-build

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe"" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)

Comment: The accepted answer in the potential duplicate is a workaround, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24627797/366335) for an actual fix if a space-containing path is indeed your problem.

Comment: The suggestions would only be relevant **if** the install path (current *or* original) contained spaces. What did you get back from the `python -m pip install pyodbc` execution?

Comment: Hi Bryan .I have edited the question above to include what error i actually see on console..meanwhile i tried what you said......C:\Users\elyon>python -m pip install pyodbc        ................
Collecting pyodbc
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyodbc
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable
(use --allow-external pyodbc to allow).
  No distributions at all found for pyodbc

Comment: Important clause in the message...`Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pyodbc to allow).` What happens when you run with the `--allow-external` switch?

Comment: hi bryan ...is this what you wanted me to try :  python -m pip install --allow-external pyodbc  ?  i tried this :C:\Users\elyon>python pip install --allow-external pyodbc
C:\Python33\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'pip'  .....

Comment: There also seems to be some confusion with python versions...your question mentions python 3.4, but the error message references python 3.3. Make sure you've got the correct version referenced in your path.

Comment: i have updated the question ..i switched over to python 3.3 but did'nt update the question ..can i join you in the chat room as this problem is taking a lot of time so if you could just walk me though it ,would be very helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69227/discussion-between-elyon-and-bryan-eargle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows with Python 3.3, the easiest way to install `pyodbc` is to use the provided [installers](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/list).

You should then be able to manage future upgrades using `pip` if you so desire.

```
C:\Python33\Scripts> .\pip.exe install --upgrade --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc
```

> Requirement already up-to-date: pyodbc in c:\python33\lib\site-packages